# Change Database Output

Tags: mysql, database, forms

I have a form setup and the data goes into a mysql database. There are several parts where the choice is both a numerical and a written rating - 1 - poor, 2 - fair, 3 - good, 4 - excellent. The field in the database is set to varchar with a length of 20. However, the output only returns the written portion - poor, fair, good, excellent, dropping the numerical. I want to either include the numerical with the written or just use the numerical itself. Can someone explain how I would set this up.

I am assuming the changes I need to make are in the php form itself - I am supplying a sample of the code and what I think I need to change - just want to verify before I do so.

```
<select name="programRating" class="pure-input-1">
                        <option value="">Select Rating...</option>
                        <option value="Poor" <?php if($_POST['programRating'] == "Poor") echo "selected"; ?>>1 - Poor</option>
                        <option value="Fair" <?php if($_POST['programRating'] == "Fair") echo "selected"; ?>>2 - Fair</option>
                        <option value="Good" <?php if($_POST['programRating'] == "Good") echo "selected"; ?>>3 - Good</option>
                        <option value="Excellent" <?php if($_POST['programRating'] == "Excellent") echo "selected"; ?>>4 - Excellent</option>
                      </select>

<select name="programRating" class="pure-input-1">
                        <option value="">Select Rating...</option>
                        <option value="Poor" <?php if($_POST['programRating'] == "1-Poor") echo "selected"; ?>>1 - Poor</option>
                        <option value="Fair" <?php if($_POST['programRating'] == "2-Fair") echo "selected"; ?>>2 - Fair</option>
                        <option value="Good" <?php if($_POST['programRating'] == "3-Good") echo "selected"; ?>>3 - Good</option>
                        <option value="Excellent" <?php if($_POST['programRating'] == "4-Excellent") echo "selected"; ?>>4 - Excellent</option>
                      </select>
```

Comment: You can use dictionary table or [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html). I'd prefer the former, and [that's why](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values which are stored in your database are the ones you specify in the "value" attribute of each "option".

So put the numbers in the "value" attribute instead of the text.

Comment: Can you have both numbers and text in the value field, so that it returns both, or am I limited to either the number or the text.